# Cropping a single text line from image Using Opencv-Python

Tags: python, image, opencv

I would like to crop an image that contain many lines of handwriting using **Opencv-Python**.

For Example: (1picture with 4 lines)

*Scrawny Kids Handwriting*

*the quick brown fox jumps overs the lazy dog*

*1234567890*

*THE QUICK BORWN FOX JUMPS OVERS THE LAZY DOG*

**And the result would come out with 4 pictures of each line as follows:**

*Picture1*: Will be a cropped image "Scrawny Kids Handwriting"

*Picture2*: Will be a cropped image "the quick bowrn fox jumps overs the lazy dog"

*Picture3*: Will be a cropped image said "1234567890"

*Picture4*: Will be a cropped image "THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG"

**Please show me what are some ways to do this?**

Thank you.

Comment: We tend to help people that show some effort...

Comment: Study abut edge detection, segmentation and tesseract etc online. You will find lots of good materials and code.